# Integrate two JSON result by decode it then encode it again

Tags: php, json, api

I have a JSON data in **ip/api/channels.php**

so using php I get the JSON data from that link and decode the data then encode and echo it again,
and this is the php code for that operation in **home.php file** :

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('ip/api/channels.php');
$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

and this is the JSON result after open it:

```
[
{
cat: "Kids",
cat_ar: "اطفال",
channels: [
{
id: "35",
title: "FIX & FOXI",
image: "uploads/fix.png",
streamname: "15",
enable: "1",
cat: "Kids",
app: "giga"
},
{
id: "185",
title: "Nickelodeon HD",
image: "uploads/nick.png",
streamname: "100",
enable: "1",
cat: "Kids",
app: "giga2"
}
]
},
{
cat: "Sports",
cat_ar: "رياضة",
channels: [
{
id: "1",
title: "BEIN SPORTS 1080 1HD ",
image: "uploads/bein1.png",
streamname: "1x",
enable: "0",
cat: "Sports",
app: "bein1"
},
{
id: "176",
title: "MBC PRO SPORTS 3",
image: "uploads/mbcpro3.png",
streamname: "mbcpro3",
enable: "1",
cat: "Sports",
app: "nile3"
}
]
}
]
```

it's right and so perfect
**but** I want to get contents from multiple links and decode data of all links then encode data and echo all of it in one new link of **ip/api/home.php** and this is what I tried:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://ip/api/channels.php');
$json2 = file_get_contents('http://ip/api/services.php');
$json3=json.json2;
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$data1 = json_decode($json2,true);
echo json_encode($data);
echo json_encode($data1);
?>
```

but the result of JSON is:

```
[{"cat":"Kids","cat_ar":"\u0627\u0637\u0641\u0627\u0644","channels":[{"id":"35","title":"FIX & FOXI","image":"uploads\/fix.png","streamname":"15","enable":"1","cat":"Kids","app":"giga"},{"id":"78","title":"MBC 3","image":"uploads\/mbc3.png","streamname":"mbc3.stream_360p","enable":"1","cat":"Kids","app":"nile3"},{"id":"85","title":"NAT GEO KIDS","image":"uploads\/natgeokids.png","streamname":"spacetoon3.stream_360p","enable":"1","cat":"Kids","app":"nile3"},{"id":"185","title":"Nickelodeon HD","image":"uploads\/nick.png","streamname":"100","enable":"1","cat":"Kids","app":"giga2"}]},{"cat":"Sports","cat_ar":"\u0631\u064a\u0627\u0636\u0629","channels":[{"id":"1","title":"BEIN SPORTS 1080 1HD ","image":"uploads\/bein1.png","streamname":"1x","enable":"0","cat":"Sports","app":"bein1"},{"id":"176","title":"MBC PRO SPORTS 3","image":"uploads\/mbcpro3.png","streamname":"mbcpro3","enable":"1","cat":"Sports","app":"nile3"}]}][{"title":"enterprise","data":{"title":"GIORG","price":"$450","details":{"speed":"000","ip":"host"}},"image":"url"},{"title":"peruser","data":{"title":"GIORG","price":"$450","details":{"speed":"000","ip":"host"}},"image":"url"}]
```

they are integrated together but they appear in one line and not in JSON structure
so what should I do to integrate the 2 links in one JSON result correctly

if you need to see the content of second link services.php this is the JSON result of it before integrated with first link:

```
[
{
title: "enterprise",
data: {
title: "GIORG",
price: "$450",
details: {
speed: "000",
ip: "host"
}
},
image: "url"
},
{
title: "peruser",
data: {
title: "GIORG",
price: "$450",
details: {
speed: "000",
ip: "host"
}
},
image: "url"
}
]
```

I have tried everything but nothing work with me

Comment: [merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) them before encoding.

Comment: json_encode(array($data1,$data2));

Comment: I tried the two solution you said it works fine thanks a lot you both save my day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that you are trying to concat string instead of arrays, try this istead:

```
echo json_encode(
   array_merge( /* or may be just `array` */
       json_decode(
           file_get_contents('http://ip/api/channels.php'),
           true
       ),
       json_decode(
           file_get_contents('http://ip/api/services.php'),
           true
       )
   )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the forward snippet

```
$links = [
    'services' => 'http://ip/api/services.php',
    'channels' => 'http://ip/api/channels.php'
];
$result = [];
foreach($links as $key => $link) {
    $json = json_decode($link, true);
    if (null !== $error = json_last_error_msg()) {
        throw new Exception(sprintf('Json with key "%s" malformated ! Error: %s', $key, $error));
    }

    $result[$key] = $json;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

I'll decode all the links into an array with as key the name of the file.

Then it encode back to JSON and echo it